# $ \cos(\hat{A})BC+ A\cos(\hat{B})C+ AB\cos(\hat{C})=\frac {A^2 + B^2 + C^2}{2} $

Tags: reference-request, trigonometry

What more can be said about the identity derived from law of cosines (motivation below)$$ \cos(\widehat{A})BC+ A\cos(\widehat{B})C+ AB\cos(\widehat{C})+=\frac {A^2 + B^2 + C^2}{2} \tag{IV}$$

RHS seems as if operator $\cos(\widehat{\phantom{X}})$ is being applied consecutively to terms of ABC, I tried to represent it in an analogous way to the Laplacian operator convention, but maybe there are more common ways of representing RHS using some operator and sigma notation ( please let me know if there is).

My question is : Are there any identities/structures relating or looking similar to IV, I apologize if this looks like a general fishing expedition question but I can not think of anything more that I can add to this post at this stage. Thank you

Motivation for IV,

Let $A,B,C$ be a triangle.

Let $\widehat{C}  = \widehat{AB}$ stand for the Angle opposite to side C between the sides A and B, then the law of cosines for all three sides can be written as $$ A^2 + B^2 - 2 AB\cos(\widehat{C}) = C^2 \tag{I} $$ 
$$ A^2 + C^2 - 2 AC\cos(\widehat{B}) = B^2 \tag{II} $$ 
$$ B^2 + C^2 - 2 BC\cos(\widehat{A}) = A^2 \tag{III} $$ 
Adding $I ,II,III$ and juggling the terms we get :

$$  AB\cos(\widehat{C})+AC\cos(\widehat{B})+BC\cos(\widehat{A}) =\frac {A^2 + B^2 + C^2}{2} \tag{IV} $$

Comment: An attractively symmetrical formula!

Comment: @user6312: I agree. @Arjang: I'd prove this without appealing to the law of cosines. Indeed, in the usual trigonometric proof of the law of cosines you start by writing $c = a \cos{\beta} + b \cos{\alpha}$ and multiply this by $c$. Now do this for each side, add the three resulting equalities up and divide by two to get (IV). In order to get the law of cosines you write $a^2 + b^2 - c^2$ using these expressions and solve for $c^2$.

Comment: Oddly enough, this looks (to me) quite related to my answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38930/how-to-show-determinant-of-a-specific-matrix-is-nonnegative/49133#49133  (this would be the case for N=3, for N>3 we have the inequality)

Comment: @Theo : tx for the tip, I will be using it for revision.

Comment: Do you want to generalize $IV$ for quadrilaterals, pentagons, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

REMARK: It seems now to me that OP is looking for generalizations of $\text{IV}$ type relations valid for quadrilaterals, pentagons, etc., and not other triangle trigonometric relations, as I exemplified below.

---

[image]

*Notation*: Consider a triangle with angles $A$, $B$, $C$ and opposite sides $a$, $b$, $c$.

It is known that *there  exists only three distinct relations between
the angles and the sides*. For instance the system

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{a}{\sin A} &=&\frac{b}{\sin B}   \\
\frac{a}{\sin A} &=&\frac{c}{\sin C}\tag{1}  \\
A+B+C &=&\pi;  
\end{eqnarray}$$

or this equivalent (yours (I),(II),(III))

$$\begin{eqnarray}
a^{2} &=&b^{2}+c^{2}-2bc\cos A  \\
b^{2} &=&c^{2}+a^{2}-2ac\cos B \tag{2}\\
c^{2} &=&a^{2}+b^{2}-2ab\cos C  
\end{eqnarray}$$
are two of them.  Another is 
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\tan \frac{A+B}{2}}{\tan \frac{A-B}{2}} &=&\frac{a+b}{a-b}  
\\
\frac{\tan \frac{B+C}{2}}{\tan \frac{B-C}{2}} &=&\frac{b+c}{b-c} \tag{3}\\
\frac{\tan \frac{C+A}{2}}{\tan \frac{C-A}{2}} &=&\frac{c+a}{c-a},  
\end{eqnarray}$$

from which one can derive

$$\begin{equation}
\frac{\tan \frac{A+B}{2}}{\tan \frac{A-B}{2}}+\frac{\tan \frac{B+C}{2}}{\tan 
\frac{B-C}{2}}+\frac{\tan \frac{C+A}{2}}{\tan \frac{C-A}{2}}=\frac{a+b}{a-b}+%
\frac{b+c}{b-c}+\frac{c+a}{c-a}.\tag{4}
\end{equation}$$

Also from

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\tan \frac{A-B}{2} &=&\frac{a-b}{a+b}\cot \frac{C}{2}   \\
\tan \frac{B-C}{2} &=&\frac{b-c}{b+c}\cot \frac{A}{2}\tag{5} \\
\tan \frac{C-A}{2} &=&\frac{c-a}{c+a}\cot \frac{B}{2},  
\end{eqnarray}$$

follows

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\tan \frac{A-B}{2} \tan \frac{C}{2}+\tan \frac{B-C}{2} \tan \frac{A}{2}+\tan \frac{C-A}{2}\tan \frac{B}{2} &=&\frac{a-b}{a+b}+\frac{b-c}{b+c}+\frac{c-a}{c+a}. \; (6)\end{eqnarray}$$

As for a reference I looked at my old trigonometry text book *Compêndio de
Trigonometria* (in Portuguese) by J. Jorge Calado. The system $\left(
3\right) $ is the law of tangents ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_tangents)) and $\left(
5\right) $ can be deduct from $\left( 3\right) $ by applying the relation $A+B+C=\pi $ to get 
\begin{eqnarray}
\tan \frac{A+B}{2} &=&\tan \left( \frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{C}{2}\right) =\cot 
\frac{C}{2}=\left( \tan \frac{C}{2}\right) ^{-1}\tag{7}    
\end{eqnarray}
and similar to $\tan \frac{B+C}{2}$ and $\tan \frac{C+A}{2}$.